# Custom membership provider not logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I've got a problem with writing my own membership and role providers.
In my MySQL db users are stored in a table consisting of four columns:
username | password | priviligeLevel | logDate

Now, what I want to achieve is making the login mechanism work.
I've created a class extending MembershiProvider, but only the method ValidateUser ( which works fine). What else should I override?
My RoleProvider works well, giving the correct privilige levels for given user.

Comment: Just override whichever one's you need: [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) under the "Methods" section.  There are several that seem quite useful (FindUsersByName, ChangePassword, GetAllUsers, etc).

Comment: You say `ValidateUser` works fine, so what does not work fine?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to override the methods that you'll want to use. [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) exposes all of the actions you typically expect to see in an authorization engine, so, for example, if you need to allow the user to change their password then override `ChangePassword`, etc.

Luckily the source code for the built in Membership Providers [has been released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx), and should provide a good guide for implementing your own.